# Prevent creating multiple instances of a socket listening class

Tags: flutter, dart, socket.io, bloc

I'm currently using socket.io within my flutter application to handle messaging. I am using Bloc to manage the chat state (which includes the socket). Then, I'm using a separate `ChatSocketListener` class to handle incoming events. Here's my setup:

```
...
class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  ChatSocketListener _chatSocketListener;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _chatSocketListener = ChatSocketListener(context);
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
      _chatSocketListener = ChatSocketListener(context);
    });
    super.initState();
  }

 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<ChatBloc, ChatState>(
      listenWhen: (previous, current) {
        if (current.socket != null) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      },
      listener: (context, state) {
        setState(() {
          _chatSocketListener = ChatSocketListener(context);
        });  
      },
      builder: (context, state) {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: ChatAppBar(),
            body: Container(
              child: ChatBody(),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

I have a _chatSocketListener stateful variable that gets created and updated every time my `ChatBloc` state changes, as you can see in the Bloc listener. This keeps the socket updated with the latest `ChatBloc` state, which I need.

Now, here's my `ChatSocketListener` class.

```
class ChatSocketListener {
  BuildContext context;

  ChatSocketListener(this.context) {
    print('SOCKET LISTENER HAS BEEN INITIALIZED');
    if (context != null) {
      ChatBloc chatBloc = BlocProvider.of<ChatBloc>(context);
      final chatState = chatBloc.state;
      if (chatState?.socket != null) {
        chatState.socket.on('testEvent', (data) async {
          if (chatState.messagesLoading) {
            chatBloc.add(ChatEvent.testEvent());
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Everything works, but with a major problem. Every time the ChatBloc is updated, the `_chatSocketListener` gets updated with the latest context. However, the previous instance of `ChatSocketListener` doesn't seem to get disposed. This causes the terminal to print

```
SOCKET LISTENER HAS BEEN INITIALIZED
SOCKET LISTENER HAS BEEN INITIALIZED
SOCKET LISTENER HAS BEEN INITIALIZED
SOCKET LISTENER HAS BEEN INITIALIZED
SOCKET LISTENER HAS BEEN INITIALIZED
```

Then, all of my socket events get called multiple times.

I've tried creating an update context method in my `ChatSocketListener` class like so:

```
  void update(newContext) {
    context = newContext;
  }
```

and

```
setState(() {
  _chatSocketListener.update(context);
});
```

but that doesn't actually update the `ChatSocketListener`.

Any help is greatly appreciated. thanks

Comment: Why exactly are you creating new instance of `ChatSocketListener`? Why can't you create a method to handle it?

Comment: I was initially doing a method, without a class - but that still gives me the same problem of initializing that method multiple times

Comment: any updates on this?